# ORACLE DB 24HRS RECORD COUNT

Tags: oracle

Is there a way in oracle dB to See how many records in a table got inserted updated and deleted in the schema? Right now I am using USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS and I am having an issue if I want to get the daily count then I have to gather stats on the table on daily basis which I want to avoid cuz a lot of my tables having millions of records and gather stats will take a lot of time to run? Can some one head me in a right direction. I will really appreciate all the help. Thanks

Comment: do you have any activity/timestamp field on the tables?  You can also take a look at oracle flashback

Answer (score 0):

I have few advices :

- SYS.DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS gives you totalnumbers ...
- If you want daily counts, you can alternatively alter your tables to store insert update delete dates on your table (soft delete , maybe even soft update ...)
  *But i think , you can use a tool to monitor it. My tool is : Real Time Oracle Monitoring and Performance Analytics Tool.

You can give it a chance

Comment: Do you know if there is any table with in dB which stores daily counts?

Comment: i dont,I already asked our dba about it, he ll return to me and i ll write here to you